# How can I log a user into Forms authentication using their pass-through Windows credentials?

Tags: asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I need an application to run under Forms authentication, but automatically log someone in via their pass-through Windows credentials.  So, essentially, I need both -- Forms authentication with no login screen, just pass-through from Windows.

Obviously, I can't run both methods.  I had an idea of setting the app to Forms, with a login page that's protected by Windows, then detected their Windows username from there and then manually logging them into Forms behind-the-scenes.

How reasonable is this idea?

Answer (score 1):

Much to my surprise there is no "automatic" support for this "mixed" authentication model in ASP.NET but there are several known work-arounds that you can implement to give you what you need.

Here is a good article that discusses the relevant factors and served as a "guide" for how I recently addressed this same requirement for an MVC 3 application I was writing:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c19559/ASPNET-Mixed-Mode-Authentication.htm

I did not follow this article to the letter as I had slightly different requirements around how I dealt with roles and session timeout management but this article was a great start!  Pay close attention to thew configuration of the forms authentication keys in the machine.config and web.config files...

Good luck!